# Unix sort rows based on semicolon

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I try to sort the following file:

```
$ cat testfile
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;CMC10
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB05
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;BMD15
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB03
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3_M1;ODP47
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1_M1;TER23
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11A
```

And I get:

```
$ sort testfile
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;BMD15
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;CMC10
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB05
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1_M1;TER23
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB03
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3_M1;ODP47
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11A
```

However, I was expecting:

```
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;BMD15
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;CMC10
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11A
...
```

That is, I want all the rows with the string `ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI` before the first semicolon to come first, then the ones with `ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1`, etc.

I looked `man sort` and I tried different options like `-g` and `-k` with `-t`, but I didn't manage. How can I do it?

Comment: @Robert Harvey such questions are asked quite often here, I don't understand why it was closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting+unix

Comment: Your question isn't answerable anyway.  You told us what you were expecting, but not what you actually got.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes the OP posted it in a very bad way. However, after some cleaning it is quite clear what he wants. What I don't know if it is suited to be reopened or should still be off-topic.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35469

Answer (score 4):

Just tell `sort` that the delimiter is `;` and you want to sort based on the second column:

```
sort -t";" -k2 file
```

It returns:

```
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;BMD15
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;CMC10
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI;DEA11A
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB02
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3;HEB03
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1;HEB05
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D3_M1;ODP47
ZBOX-BATCH-SAMEDI_D1_M1;TER23
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work as I expect it to work. If I do `echo -e "1\n10" | sort -t";" -k1` I get `1` and `10` like I expect lexicographical sorting to work. But with `echo -e "1;bbb\n10;aaa" | sort -t";" -k1` I get the line with `10` first and then the `1`. What am I missing here? Strangely enough it works for `echo -e "x\nxx" | sort -t";" -k1` and `echo -e "x;bbb\nxx;aaa" | sort -t";" -k1` -- here in both cases "x" < "xx". Funnily enough if I do add `-g` (general numeric sort) its fine (1<10, and x<xx work too) it works. And `echo -e "1;bbb\n11;aaa" | sort -t";" -k1,1` works too. Hrm...

Comment: @towi strange, indeed. I suggest you to post a new question over this: we most probably are missing some parts of the docs, or some undocumented bit.